# Как в MySQL организовать связь многие-ко-многим в данном примере

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных с таблицами, но я думаю что база данных которую я спроектировал, спроектирована не верно. Вот мои таблицы:

**BOOK**

```
book_id | book_name | rubric | autor
```

**RUBRIC**

```
rubric_id | rubric_name
```

**AUTOR**

```
autor_id | first_name | last_name
```

Вот задание:

```
1. Необходимо написать каталог книг с использованием базы данных MySQL.

2. У каталога есть следующие сущности: "книга", "автор", "рубрика".
2.1. У сущности "книга" есть 4 свойства: название, фото, рубрика(и), автор(ы).
2.2. У сущности "автор" есть два свойства: имя и фамилия.
2.3. У сущности "рубрика" есть только одно свойство: название самой рубрики.
2.4. Книги, авторы и рубрики, как видно из п.2.1, имеют связь многие-ко-многим.

3. Функционал.
3.1. Добавление/редактирование/удаление:
3.1.1. Книг.
3.1.2. Авторов.
3.1.3. Рубрик.

3.3. Разумеется, в самом каталоге должен быть реализован просмотр отдельно страниц книг, авторов и рубрик.
3.3.1. На странице автора должна быть возможность увидеть список всех книг определенного автора.
3.3.2. На странице рубрики должна быть возможность увидеть список всех книг определенной рубрики.
```

Как организовать связь многие-ко-многим?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тестовые задания как раз и предназначены для **самостоятельного** решения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: [не имеет значения является ли вопрос тестовым заданием где-то или нет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044). Вопрос некачественный: слишком всеобъемлющий заголовок, не указано явно в чём конкретно проблема ("спроектирована не верно" не очень информативно). Но в виде вопроса "как в MySQL организовать связь многие-ко-многим в данном примере", он мог бы существовать после редактирования.

Comment: @jfs, согласен с вами. но ключевой момент здесь: «после редактирования».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обеспечения отношения многие-ко-многим используйте таблицы связок.

Тогда Ваша БД будет такая:

BOOK

```
book_id | book_name | book_photo
```

RUBRIC

```
rubric_id | rubric_name
```

AUTHOR

```
author_id | first_name | last_name
```

BOOK_RUBRIK

```
book_id | rubric_id
```

BOOK_AUTHOR

```
book_id | author_id
```

Comment: а в таблицах book_rubric и book_autor указывать autoincrement?

Comment: @Nevada, для чего? в этих таблицах не нужны собственные id, это только связь между другими сущностями.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица **RUBRIC**: `rubric_id, rubric_name`
Таблица **AUTOR**: `autor_id, first_name, last_name`
Таблица **BOOK**: `book_id, book_name, book_photo`
Таблица **BOOK_AUTOR**: `book_id, autor_id`
Таблица **BOOK_RUBRIC**: `book_id, rubric_id`